# Can a Dynamics CRM 2011 Outlook Client connect to a CRM 4 server?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I found some info on CRM 4 Outlook Clients to be able to connect to a CRM 2011 server instance (after applying at least roll-up 10 or so), but is it possible the other way around?

I mean, can a CRM 2011 Outlook Client connect to an old CRM 4 server (in this case on-
premise)? Our customer will have CRM 4 and 2011 servers and some employees need to be able to connect with both (if possible).

Comment: I believe that irregardless, you only can have one main organization in the client, anyway. You can only sync your mail with one instance of CRM at a time. Is that a limitation that you can live with?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Thank you for responding, but it didn't answer my question. I was aware of that limitation.

Comment: I know, I know. Hence the comment, not the answer form. Sometimes it helps to help others in the right trail of thoughts. I agree BTW with @AdamV. Vote him up if you like his reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The new client simply will not work with CRM 4.0. Upgrade rollouts always have to be done server first, for this reason, leaving you to upgrade the outlook clients as soon as possible afterwards.

Time to get that CRM 4 instance upgraded (maybe just as a second organisation on the same CRM 2011 server you already have).

Comment: thank you for answering. You are right. The CRM 2011 client doesn't support CRM 4 server connections. I got the same answer via Twitter from Christoph (@ccelar) and Microsoft (@MSFTDynamics), see my twitter account [https://twitter.com/mdocter](https://twitter.com/mdocter).